# how to show image by clicking view details from database in boostrap model through ajax jquery in codeignter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Upto this code i have got name, description, etc but image not showing,

**Attached below screenshot:**

[image]

```
$('.view_detail').click(function(){

      var id = $(this).attr('id'); //get the attribute value
      $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo base_url('admin/get_products');?>",
          data:{id : id},
          post:'GET',
          dataType:'JSON',
          success:function(response) {
            $('#product_name').html(response.pro_name);
            $('#menu').html(response.menu);
            $('#description').html(response.description);
            $('#img1').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/products/">'  + response.img1 + '</img>');
            $('#img2').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/products/">'  + response.img2 + '</img>');
            $('#img3').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/products/">'  + response.img3 + '</img>');
            // html('<img>' + data + '</img>);
            // html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/products/img1" />');
            $('#price').html(response.price);
            $('#discount').html(response.discount);
            $('#offer_price').html(response.offer_price);

            $('#show_modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: true});
        }
      });
  });
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Have you checked what are you getting in console error, console base_url(), check properly in inspect element, please add here html code also.

Comment: Do some basic debugging.  Check the network tab in your browser's devtools, and inspect the request and response.  Does the response include the images as you expect?  Check the rendered HTML in your modal - are the paths to the images correct?  Copy-paste those generated URLs into your browser, do they work, are the images really accessible there? PS - [`post` is not a valid `$.ajax()` parameter](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - did you mean `method`?

Comment: no error has shown in console.

Comment: how to add html code 
how to request and response in network